# Do I have to start a new project if the '1 month without any rules' has expired?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have been working with Firestore and am used to deploying my website and getting it tested by people. One month has gone by and now things don't seem to be working on the deployed website. I believe it's because I have not written any rules during this time. I read that I would lose access to my database if I did so.

1. Can I apply the rules anytime I'd like and it'll get back on or should I start a whole new project and reset the configs?

I just don't think writing rules at this point is important given that my project will undergo many critical alterations in the foreseeable future

2. Is there a simple way I that I can NOT write rules now and leave everything working? I changed the original rule to a date in the future, but it seems that when I deploy my project, it'll reset the rules.

```
match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2027, 5, 28);
      //seems to get reset to to original date
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when you set up Firebase hosting on your project, a file `firebase.rules` is created. If you build your project without updating that file, the rules in the firebase console get overwritten.

Comment: If you want to prevent deploying Firestore security rules, run `firebase deploy --only hosting`.